# Spinoza: finding examples of a definite cause: where if no definite cause be granted, the effect cannot follow

Tags: causality, spinoza

When we typically think of cause and effect, we start with an event such as a death of a person and we ask what was the cause.  For example, we might say that the cause of death was a heart attack.

Spinoza, on the other hand, talks about a "definite cause".  A heart attack might kill someone and it could be the cause of someone's death but it is not a definite cause.  It is also possible that a person has a heart attack and survives.

Spinoza talks about "definite causes".  He writes:

> From a given definite cause an effect necessarily follows; and, on the other hand, if no definite cause be granted, it is impossible that an effect can follow.

What would be an example of a "definite cause"?  Other than cheating and adding a result as part of the event, I don't see how we can talk about definite causes.

For example, a "fatal heart attack" would always lead to death (but we've kind of cheated by adding the result to the cause).  But it does not follow that if death occurred that the person died from a "fatal heart attack".  Clearly, other causes could result in the same effect.

What are examples of a definite cause (an event) such that the effect (result of the event) only exists if the "definite cause" be granted?

I understand that Spinoza sees God as self-caused and the cause of everything else.  Other than God, what would be an example of a definite cause and its effect?

I think that if I could understand other examples, it would really help me to be clear on the concept as Spinoza is using it.

The only example that I can think of is if we add the cause to the effect.  So, I could say that "death by fatal heart attack" has a definite cause of a "fatal heart attack."

Is this what Spinoza means or does he have some other usage in mind?

Comment: It is possible to survive a heart attack because "heart attack" is a vague term that covers a range of phenomena that we do not distinguish for lack of practical means to distinguish them most of the time. But there are types of heart attacks that definitely cause death in virtue of their (invisible to us) physical properties. Those would be the "fatal heart attacks" that are definite causes, but not merely because we added the "fatal" qualification. They have independently describable intrinsic properties that make them fatal.

Comment: After your quote see axiom 4 : *The knowledge of an effect depends on and involves the knowledge of a cause*, and there's another [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Spinoza) of "definite" to "determinate", and Spinoza is famous for his ardent determinism with strongest PSR. Due to Hume's problem (Leibniz also hinted) as you've rightly concerned, for Spinoza cause-and-effect is the deterministic mode of both ideas (functions are examples) and extended things (physical laws), in above non-deterministic counterexample, you haven't arrived at the *definite* cause yet...